Help Formatting a set with two conditions
I am trying to format the following in LaTeX:

I have tried using an array, but I can't centre the left hand side and don't know how to make the big bar in the middle. Any assistance formatting this would be appreciated.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal example of what   you tried.

Aside: Be sure to write f\colon G\to W, not f: G\to W for the expression to the left of the vertical bar. (Why? Because TeX and LaTeX define : to be of type mathrel.)

Here's a solution that (a) uses a two-column array environment, (b) places a minipage in the right-hand column, and (c) employs an enumerate environment inside the minipage environment. Note that the array will be centered horizontally automatically if you place it inside a display-math environment.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength\mylen
% measure width of 'minipage' environment:
\settowidth\mylen{(1)\quad$f(hu)=f(h)$ for all $u\in U_f$ an open set in $G$}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\{ \begin{array}{@{} l | l @{}}
f\colon G\to W &
\begin{minipage}{\mylen}
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,nosep,label=(\arabic*)]
\item $f(bg)=\Delta(b)^{1/2}\sigma(b)f(g),\ \forall b\in B,\ \forall g\in G$ 
\item $f(hu)=f(h)$ for all $u\in U_f$ an open set in $G$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{array} \right\}
\]

\end{document}


Thanks! This works brilliantly.

Something like this might do
Each item i'd here write
\item $f(bg)=\Delta(b)...$  

full MWE
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,varwidth,enumitem}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Line just to show that it is centered

\noindent
\rule\textwidth{1pt}%

\[
  \left\{
    f: G \to W
    \:
    \middle\vert
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}% it readjusts it self
      \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),nosep, leftmargin=*]
      \item foobar
      \item bar foo
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{varwidth}
  \right\}
\]
\end{document}



This looks like it will work, thanks! How do I centre it in display mode? I am not familiar with the varwidth package and it seems that wrapping it in {center} does not work.

@ToddBurnett it is not centered in your image, and IMO it should not be, looks bad.

By centred I just mean I want it to be in the middle of the page when putting it in display mode.

@ToddBurnett It already is in display math mode. and it is centered, Add \noindent \rule\textwidth{4mm}% on a line above \[, varwith here just makes a box that shrinks down to the longest line in the list (or \textwidth).

hmm that just gives me a long black box above what I want. In my document, it is aligned the entire thing to the left copying your code verbatim @daleif

@ToddBurnett Update your question and add what you have (do not delete what is already there. I cannot see your doc so I don't know what you are doing. Provide an MWE (similar to my post) that shows your problem.

No need for enumerate in this simple case.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{\,
    f: G \to W
    \;\middle\vert\;
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% like in cases
    \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{ }l@{}}
    (1) & $f(bg)=\Delta(b)^{1/2}\sigma(b)f(g),\ \forall b\in B,\ \forall g\in G$ \\
    (2) & $f(hu)=f(h)$ for all $u\in U_f$ an open set in $G$
    \end{tabular}
  \,\right\}
\]

\end{document}


